# Json to line chart

Tags: javascript, json, linegraph

I have JSON data like

`{ "Name": "Name1", "TotalTickets": "1", "requestMonth": "1" }` - somewhat like

```
name  count  Month
a      1      1
b      2      2
c      1      3
-      -      -
-      -      12
```

so on I want to plot it in a line graph, by x-axis as count y-axis as month like Jan, Feb. name like line how many counts in the month it should show in line
how to do?

Comment: How is that a json data again? Json data is key-value pair.
If no key no value

Comment: {
  "Name": "Name1",
  "TotalTickets": "1",
  "requestMonth": "1"
}

Comment: Have you tried existing chart libraries like d3.js? Should be pretty easy using one of these - for example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148545/line-chart-of-json-data-in-d3/48060114)

Comment: no, bcz i have 3 keys in json. i want that name shoulb be in line format, x-axis has tickets and y has months